# Hooking in a Specific Portlet - Liferay

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay, hook, assets

Good day! I've been hooking the asset-tags-selector page and javascript to customize a particular portlet in Liferay & it works well.
But the files that I have been customizing is also being used by other portlets such as blogs and announcements.

Is there a way to use hooks only for a particular portlet? If not through hooks, how?

Hope you can help me

Comment: asset-tags-selector is stand alone feature/component itself portal-wide. used in many collaboration portlets(webcontent, blogs, forum etc). You may write logic in your hook itself to have changes applied to only portlet you want and for rest, it works as it is. BTW, Would you elaborate more on your requirement?

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya Hello! Thank you for replying. I just need to allow the user to only select tags and not add or type different ones that are not in the selection. Thus in my hook, I removed the add and suggestions button and kept the select button and I also disabled the key press functionality so they wont be able to type

Comment: You can add `Portlet portlet = (Portlet)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.RENDER_PORTLET);  Integer.valueOf(portlet.getPortletId()) == xxx` check to separate code where xxx is the id of the portlet. You can find `portletId` of your desired portlet in `liferay-portlet.xml` of your portal.